# Is it possible to reduce WhatsApp "msgstore.db" file size?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, storage

My WhatsApp backup file (`msgstore-**.db.crypt12`) size can reach up to 380MB+ for a single file. Because WhatsApp automatically backup chats every day and will keep the 7 most recent backups, my phone will store up to 2GB worth of these files.

In case anyone's wondering, my phone is not rooted, but I have the WhatsApp `key` and `wa.db` files, so I can decrypt (and re-encrypt) the `msgstore.db` file. What I have tried is to manually delete some messages in the `messages` table in the `msgstore.db` file, it sure reduces the file size, but then it fails when I try to restore WhatsApp chats using that file. Also, I have tried to clear chats in some groups that have a lot of messages using the *Clear chat* feature, this deletes the messages in the `messages` table, but doesn't reduce the `msgstore.db` file size, I guess the deleted messages are moved to another table which I don't know where.

I don't need a trick to stop WhatsApp auto backup, I just want to reduce the `msgstore.db` file size, is it possible?

Comment: https://sqliteforensictoolkit.com/how-not-to-examine-sqlite-wal-files sqlite3 databases are quiet complicated. entries won't deleted immediately. instead, content is flagged as deleted and preserved, sometimes collected in .wal files. start with fresh database

Comment: @alecxs I don't think WhatsApp databases are merely SQLite DBs. `.crypt12` indicates they are encrypted, possibly with some proprietary scheme.

Comment: @IrfanLatif WhatsApp databases are SQLite DBs with encryption applied to them. There are tools available for decrypting WhatsApp databases such as [this one](https://github.com/ElDavoo/WhatsApp-Crypt14-Crypt15-Decrypter). This will give you an unencrypted version of the database which you can then read just like any other SQLite database.